# How to get utc datetime based on user's current datetime in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs, utc

I try to get datetime based on user's current datetime. For example, if I want to get the start of the current date in utc,

```
const start = new Date()
start.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
```

if I want to get the end of the current date in utc,

```
const end = new Date()
end.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999)
```

but when I console.log start, it's

```
Sun Jun 05 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

May I know why there's this "(Pacific Daylight Time)"? )

So what if I want to get 5 days ago of current datetimt? Like if now local datetime is 2:35pm pst, how do I get 5 days ago 2:35 pm but in utc (which should be 7:35pm right?) Thanks!

Comment: Console log this instead: `start.toUTCString()`

Comment: Hi @Scratch'N'Purr, thanks! This does give a UTC time! May I know how to get a utc datetime based on local time if also using setUTCHours?

Comment: You can still use `toUTCString`. `setUTCHours` will set your hours for your datetime object to the hours based on universal time. Therefore, based on your example, if you console log `start.toUTCString()` after you run `start.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`, you'll get something similar to `'Mon, 06 Jun 2022 00:00:00 GMT'`

Comment: Hi @Scratch'N'Purr, for the start and end one, I send the start or end variable to backend and it works. So I guess backend accept something like "Sun Jun 05 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)", not 'Mon, 06 Jun 2022 00:00:00 GMT'. Should I send a date obj to the backend? If I send something like fiveDaysAgo= new Date(date.getTime()), and use fiveDaysAgo.setDate(date.getEDate()-5), will this fiveDaysAgo be utc or local when sent to backend? Thanks!

Comment: @Ying—please don't ask questions in comments, edit the original question. If using non–UTC methods, then local values are set. To set UTC, values, use UTC methods. To subtract UTC days, use `fiveDaysAgo.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() - 5)`